# Running SQL queries in Excel

Tags: mysql, reporting, excel

I am working in a company, and for some reason, I'm being dumped to do statistics.

I'm given a load of data dumps, and I am made to do some really repetitive data massage.

The first solution, obviously, is to write a script to do this for me. I can't. I am not allowed to download servers into my PC, being a PHP programmer, I can't do this.

Secondly, I thought of importing these txt files into a MySQL database and running queries on them. Again, I can't. I'm not even allowed to have a MySQL database in my PC.

**Firstly, let me describe what I'm hoping to achieve.**
I'm given a data dump, and I'm trying to run a query similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM `price` FROM <this excel sheet> WHERE `date`>`somedate` AND `type`=`sometype`
```

I've tried to do some research on running queries on Excel, which gave me decent results. I could use autofilter/advanced filters to filter out results that are irrelevant to me. And then I can use autosum to achieve the sum of the price.

This is however, a way too lengthy process. It's much better than doing it manually, but it's not good enough for me. I am looking for a programmatical way to solve this.

Conditions: 
I cant install any apache/mySQL servers into my PC. I am however, allowed to install softwares.

What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: You should search another company LoL.
Anyway I think Office let you do something like this but only with Access Database integration.

Comment: Would they let you run Mongoose?

Comment: I am on the verge of looking for another company :/ this is becoming way too annoying.

Comment: @Jodes whats mongoose?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use Access like Claudio, suggested?

Comment: @JamesJenkins access rights issues from my office. I'm not sure whether they allow me to use that.

Comment: @He Hui, they should it is Microsoft tool, it comes with the office products.  You might need to get an upgrade Office Package.  If you have never used Access, but you have PHP experiance you should be fine.  It is like a super version of Excel. Kind of between Excel and MySql.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I highly believe this only come with the 3 cores (ie. word,excel,powerpoint). I can't buy an upgrade, so, fingers crossed when I check my computer tomorrow lol.

Comment: Consider a text file (.csv) with perl (not too distant from your php experience) connecting using DBD::CSV.

Comment: isn't this just a `sumif` or am I missing something?

Comment: @scott i do not understand your question. what do you mean by `sumif`

Comment: @MichaelT I believe you perl needs a database connection as well right? my problem is because I can't create the connection(they blocked it). Regardless of me having a database in any format.

Comment: @HeHui the perl [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV-0.38/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) reads a .csv file as if it was a database.  From the doc `This one is based on the SQL "engine" SQL::Statement and the abstract DBI driver DBD::File and implements access to so-called CSV files (Comma Separated Values). Such files are often used for exporting MS Access and MS Excel data.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is not the worst tool for doing "repetitive data massage" (actually, it is often my first choice for such tasks). The key point is that you learn using formulas and VBA programming. Using VBA, you can automate  (ok, almost) **everything** in Excel which you can do manually otherwise. A query like yours above will need a few lines more in VBA, written in a procedural style, but you can immediatly store the result in an aggregate sheet, format it nicely, add some code for loading your dump into an Excel sheet beforehand and so automate the whole process, not just the query part.

Comment: I certainly did not pick excel. If you want to discuss about "how to do it", anyone in the right mind would be doing it during data extraction (i.e. using SQL). However, I don't really have a choice :/

I'm not too sure whether VBA is even allowed in my PC. *pulls hair out of frustration* But I'll give it a go.

Comment: @HeHui: you seem to be biased. If you have Excel installed, you will most probably will already have VBA. SQL will only make your "query" part a little bit easier, I would not overrate that, have the whole process in mind. And if you take just one minute and google for "Using Excel as database", you will find plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Well the only thing I can say is, every country works differently. I am pretty sure I dont have VBA installed. I read your initial message wrongly, missing out "not the". I am not biased against excel, and I will definitely try anything to simplify this process.

Comment: @HeHui: open Excel, press "Alt-F11" and see if the VBA editor opens - normally it does. VBA is typically part of a standard Excel installation.

Comment: GOSH! I have VBA! I'm going to try it now. Never written VB scripts though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like [FreeSQLEditor](http://www.werysoft.com/FreeSQLEditor.aspx) to make an ODBC connection to your Excel file. In that instance, your sheets would become tables and then you can perform queries on it.

UPDATE: FreeSQLEditor is shareware. You can use the [ODBC Query Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/odbcquerytool/) instead

Comment: i'll try this out when I get back to office. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: I see that there's only a trial version available. Would I need to pay to use this?

Comment: I think you do. I was just giving it as an example. Here's a free one you could use http://sourceforge.net/projects/odbcquerytool/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a SQL-Server. You can do it pretty easy in Excel.

1. Concatenate Date and Type.
2. Vlookup for your new hashtag ( Date and Type)

Herewith a minimal example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgBAVSqx4789dHA2M1lQd0JaY0hidkVfQmNqbmZjX2c&usp=sharing

If you want to sum, you can use the Sumifs function.

Comment: well the problem with this is that every week, the number of records change. What I am looking for is a dynamic solution which does not need to be told `A1:A2034`, but rather, it knows how many records the column `A` has.

Comment: But you can choose the whole column A:A, don't you? You can also try to import the data into MS Access and run SQL-Queries. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should defitenely try [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), it connect to Excel (and other databases) easily, you can create SQL queries against Excel work sheets as if they were tables and let you output your data back to Excel just as easily.